# Let $X$ be a finite measure space. Assume $0\leq f_n\leq 1$ and $f_n\to1$ in $L^1$ then $f_n \to 1$ a.e

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

[image]

I think this is not actually true, but it is a qual problem from Boston College so I am being doubtfull of my counter-example.

Let $X=[0,1]$ and $f_n=1-g_n$ where $g_n$ is the typewriter sequence ($g_n\to 0$ in $L^1$ but not a.e) thus $f_n\to 1$ in $L^1$ but not a.e How is this not a counterexample?

Comment: Yours is indeed a counterexample. I think the author of hte exercise might have had in mind some additional hypotesis. For example, if $f_n\to f$, then $f=1$ a.e., as one can prove thanks to the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem

Comment: @Caffeine Yes, you can also show by fatous that $\limsup(f_n) =1$ a.e and thanks to convergence conclude $f=1$. Thank you for confirmation.

Comment: I added a Community Wiki answer. Feel free to add your proof by Fatou's lemma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This hypotesis by itself, as your counterexample shows, is not sufficient to guarantee the convergence of $f_n$, much less that $f_n\to 1$. However, if you add some additional hypotesis, the result follows. For example, the following is true:

If $f_n\to f$, $f=1$ a.e.

Proof:

In fact $1\ge f\ge 0$, and thanks to the dominated convergence theorem, we have

$$\mu(X)=\int_X fd\mu=\int_X 1d\mu\\\int_X(1-f)d\mu
=0\\
\forall_{t>0}\ \mu(\{1-f\ge t\})=0$$

Thus $f=1$ a.e.

Another proof can be found applying Fatou's lemma.
Since $0\leq f_n\leq1$ we know that $0\leq 1-f_n$ and so by Fatous Lemma $$\int_X\liminf{(1-f_n)}\leq\liminf{\int_X(1-f_n)}\stackrel{f_n\to 1(L^1)}{=}0$$
Hence a.e we have $$\liminf{(1-f_n)}=0 \implies\limsup{f_n}=1 \implies f_n\to f$$